# Overriding types in default classes after inheritance

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

Would it be possible to overwrite the interface type of the default class when I want to make an inheritance and add new parameters in the child class?

```
interface DefaultFields {
    cellphoneInput: string,
    legalCheckbox: string
}

class Default {
    submitButton:string;
    fields:DefaultFields;

    constructor(
        fields:DefaultFields = {},
        submitButton:string = `button#btn-submit-%s`,
    ) {
        this.submitButton = submitButton;
        this.fields = {
            cellphoneInput: `$input-c2c-phone`,
            legalCheckbox: `input[name="legal"]`,
            ...fields
        };
    }
}
```

In the child, I would like to add new fields and also take into account the default ones in the interface.

```
interface FormFields extends DefaultFields{
    radioToggle: string,
    checkToggle: string,
    emailField: string,
    citySelector: string,
}

export default class MainForm extends Default {

    // setting locators

    constructor() {
        let fields:FormFields = {
            radioToggle: `label[for="%s-radio-fi"]`,
            checkToggle: `label[for="%s-check-isClient"]`,
            emailField: `label[for="%s-input-email"]`,
            citySelector: `label[for="%s-select-city"]`
        };
        super(fields);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When inheriting, you can pass the necessary interface using [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), as in the simplified example below:

```js
interface DefaultFields {
    cellphoneInput: string,
    legalCheckbox: string
}

class Default<T extends DefaultFields> {
    constructor(
        public submitButton: string,
        public fields: T,
    ) { }
}

interface FormFields extends DefaultFields {
    radioToggle: string,
    checkToggle: string,
    emailField: string,
    citySelector: string,
}

class MainForm extends Default<FormFields> { }

// Examples below: 

const example1 = new Default('testButton', { cellphoneInput: '...', legalCheckbox: '...' });
const example2 = new MainForm('testButton', {
    radioToggle: `...`,
    checkToggle: `...`,
    emailField: `...`,
    citySelector: `...`,
    cellphoneInput: `...`,
    legalCheckbox: '...'
})
```

[This example is in the sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIXgVwDZgGLATYAmAzsgN4BQytyS22ADgBYD2IEAkiE5mAC5kpMFFABzADQ062COLjYAwiwgIA1gCM2ADyEixIcVQC+VKgmxxS5dFlwAeACrIIOyCDJoMcHPkIkpAB8lDK0CBwGmAhgbFAAFGF0tHya2MAIwpiaALbAYABC-LEg+qIS0snJqemZMAFkQk6VdACUlMhmZlSgkLCIKHhxOQREXm4eXna+uKOBoclQcMTAbE5s4uJyZYZSSQiqGuub28LlRi20EDlwwNhzxDsV+-kAngDKRGqxUE8XpuZLNZyABZW4gIZQHKudwQTy2Hx+ByQkYNYIdboAekxyAAojo4DkmHJyJoiGwAO5CQGRMAwwnEiAARmQAF5kJwKd57GB4gBySAiIpgEp8yQdBjMdicHh8QTIPkAOmVYuQcgUykOWl0QiVKs6rQA3BZafSiXIAExsjkQLlg0Ao-mCwrFDiq6iLZarY5bCBCAAGysV-su9C1PtOgeVIaS11u9waAaDMeSCDenzkMTiSejoclrA43F4-BzwdD6sUKjU2r0CqDfNMrSAA)